# Schedule tasks in pure cmd in windows 8

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduling

How to schedule tasks in pure cmd without any additional programs. I mean windows cmd or windows batch. For example one wants to shut down his windows on May 31 '17 at 10:24.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "pure cmd" and "without any additional programs" means no 3rd party program installation, and that any program bundled with any windows installation is still a "pure cmd" approach, what you need would be an administrator cmd shell (batch running as administrator) and the schtasks.exe (shipped with windows).

[Scrhtasts.exe (Windows) from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)

To shutdown the system at that date, for example, this should do:

```
schtasks /create /SC ONCE /ST 10:24 /SD 31/05/2017 /TN ShutdownSystem /TR "'c:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe' /s"
```

P.s.: this may work if you are not the 'administrator' account but your account has administrator privileges, but may be delayed by the windows' UAC dialog to allow to do changes.

Comment: This answer needs an initial sentence to answer the question as asked, i.e. it is not possible to access the task scheduler service using "pure" cmd.exe commands.

Comment: I was assuming commands builtin and part of every windows 8 would count as "pure cmd".

Comment: I assumed "pure cmd" meant using only built-in commands like `dir` and `copy`, which are purely part of the batch scripting language. Opening it up to any program distributed with Windows means we could run a PowerShell or VB script using the .NET or COM API for the task scheduler, but obvious schtasks.exe is the most direct approach.

Comment: let's see what the OP thinks about it. heeh